# Error: java.lang.SecurityException: execute on /home/<user>/test.sh JAR file trying to read shell file (Pljava)

Tags: postgresql, pljava

I am trying to call a pl/Sql function which calls a Java class and it reads a shell file and execute the same. I placed this shell file in my home directory.

I created a JAR using that class and installed in PostgreSQL.

However, when trying to execute in PLJava, it returns the following error:

> ERROR:  java.lang.SecurityException: execute on /home//test.sh

********** Error **********

> ERROR: java.lang.SecurityException: execute on /home//test.sh
>   SQL state: XX000

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot read and execute files from trusted PL/Java. You have to use untrusted language for this (i.e. `javau`), and you have to create the function under superuser